# Code snippet license

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I use a code snippet from ros answers, then, should my program be at least CC licensed?

What if I use an url link to the answer as a comment inside my code?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242126/code-snippet-license/) by [Luis Ruiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/14101/luis-ruiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2016-08-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not a lawer. My interpretation of the CC license is not legally valid or binding.

If you really care, hire a lawyer to interpret the license for you.

That aside, it looks like you're worried about section 4 of the license, covering restrictions:

> 4. Restrictions. The license granted in Section 3 above is expressly made subject to and limited by the following restrictions:

(a) seems to indicate that you need to include or link to the CC license within the part of your code where you used code copied from this site.

(b) seems to indicate that your code (or at least the part of it that uses code copied from this site) should be licensed under a later, similar, or compatible license. (this might include GPLv3, according to https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/licensing-considerations/compatible-licenses/ )

(c) seems to indicate that you need to include the author's name and a link to the original in your code. (username and link to the ROS answers post seems OK here).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1